# s3 bucket already exists in all stages except one

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am deploying a cloudformation serverless yaml with a S3 and S3 policy resource. I have stages `bob`, `dev`, and `stage`. Then the bucket name has pattern `mybucket-<stage>`. When I deploy to `bob`, the deployment is successful. When I try the other stages, I get error like `An error occurred: mybucket-dev already exists.` Do you know how to fix the issue?

Comment: Can you share your serverless.yml? Are you using https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-s3-deploy ?

Comment: The issue was probably due to parallel deployment. When issue occurs again, I will investigate.